# TeX is ignoring an optional value

Tags: tables

I have two `tabular` environments containing functions.  The height of the boxes containing some of these functions is taller than the inter-line spacing in `text` mode.  So, the appearance is cramped.  I want to have `\\ [1.2\baselineskip]` separating the rows.  This command is ignored.  I tried using `\\ [12\baselineskip]` in one row.  That is ignored, too.  In the following code, only `\\ [1cm]` was not ignored.  How do I get `TeX` to compile the code?  (I want to keep the `tabular` environments.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}


\noindent {\textbf{Example}} \vskip1.25mm
The following functions are increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$. \vskip1.25mm
\begin{tabular}{r @{\ }l}
{\textbf{i.)}}   &       $x^{2} + x$ \\[1.2\baselineskip]
{\textbf{ii.)}}  &       $x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7$ \\[1.2\baselineskip]
{\textbf{iii.)}} &       $x^{2} + \sqrt{x}$
\end{tabular}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent {\textbf{Example}} \vskip1.25mm
The following functions are also increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$. \vskip1.25mm
\begin{tabular}{r @{\ }l}
{\textbf{i.)}}   &       $\sqrt{x^{2} + x}$ \\[12\baselineskip]
{\textbf{ii.)}}  &       $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7}$ \\[1cm]
{\textbf{iii.)}} &       $\bigl(x^{2} + \sqrt{x}\bigr)^{3}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, I'll find it. `\baselinskip` is 0pt in tables. use `\normalbaselineskip` (why is this tagged tex-core?)

Comment: Do you really want to use tabular to enumerate items?

Comment: As an alternative: Think about `\\[1.2ex]` to improve spacing

Comment: BTW, `\bfseries` is a command, which sets the following text in bold, thus a group limits it range: `{\bfseries ...}`..`\textbf`, however, sets its argument in bold, an additional group is not needed.

Comment: @JP-Ellis  The answer is contained in the post at "Baselineskip not interpreted in a tabularx keyvalue environment."  As David Carlisle states in both posts, `\baselinskip` is `0pt` in tables and to use `\\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]` to get the spacing requested.  Why is `\baselinskip` equal to `0pt` in tables?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer  I decided to use `\\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]`.  The inter-line spacing in `text` mode is this.  To be consistent, I am using the same rule here.

Comment: @Adelyn baselineskip is 0pt mainly so that vertical lines from `|` appear continuous.

Comment: @David Carlisle  Thanks for the explanation.